changing scale of font in babel
Is there a way to change the scale of a font within babel? Specifically, the Hebrew is smaller than I'd like it. Is there a way to make it a little larger?
Here's the document I'm working with:
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{apacite} 

 

\usepackage{geometry}

\geometry{verbose,letterpaper,tmargin=1.0in,bmargin=1.0in,lmargin=1.0in,rmargin=1.0in,headheight=0.5in,headsep=0.2in,footskip=0.5in}

\usepackage[bidi=default]{babel}  
\babelprovide[import]{hebrew}


\babeltags{
  hebrew=hebrew,
  greek=greek,
  ancientgreek=ancientgreek,
  syriac=syriac,
  german=german,
} 


\babelfont{rm}{Minion Pro Medium}
\babelfont[hebrew]{rm}{SBL Hebrew}
\babelfont[ancientgreek]{rm}{Accordance}
\babelfont[greek]{rm}{Minion Pro Display}
\babelfont[syriac]{rm}{Accordance}
\babelfont[german]{rm}{1517 Gilgengart}
\babelfont{tt}{2004 Uncialis Romana}





\usepackage{setspace}









\doublespacing 

\begin{document}







\section{test}



Text:
\begin{itemize}
\item{\foreignlanguage{hebrew}{”\textsuperscript{1} בְּרֵאשִׁ֖ית בָּרָ֣א אֱלֹהִ֑ים אֵ֥ת הַשָּׁמַ֖יִם וְאֵ֥ת הָאָֽרֶץ׃ \textsuperscript{2} וְהָאָ֗רֶץ הָיְתָ֥ה תֹ֨הוּ֙ וָבֹ֔הוּ וְחֹ֖שֶׁךְ עַל־פְּנֵ֣י תְה֑וֹם וְר֣וּחַ אֱלֹהִ֔ים מְרַחֶ֖פֶת עַל־פְּנֵ֥י הַמָּֽיִם׃“} (Genesis 1:1-2 HMT-W4)}
\item{\foreignlanguage{greek}{Εἶπεν δὲ καὶ πρός τινας τοὺς πεποιθότας ἐφ’ ἑαυτοῖς ὅτι εἰσὶν δίκαιοι καὶ ἐξουθενοῦντες τοὺς λοιποὺς τὴν παραβολὴν ταύτην.}  }
\item{\foreignlanguage{ancientgreek}{Ⲉⲓⲡⲉⲛⲇⲉⲡⲣⲟⲥⲧⲓⲛⲁⲥⲧⲟⲩⲥⲡⲉ} }
\item{\foreignlanguage{syriac}{ܘܶܐܡܰܪ ܗ݈ܘܳܐ ܡܰܬ݂ܠܳܐ ܗܳܢܳܐ ܠܽܘܩܒ݂ܰܠ ܐ݈ܢܳܫ̈ܳܐ ܐܝܠܶܝܢ ܕ݁ܰܬ݂ܟ݂ܺܝܠܺܝܢ ܥܰܠ ܢܰܦ݂ܫܗܽܘܢ ܕ݁ܺܐܝܬ݂ܰܝܗܽܘܢ ܙܰܕ݁ܺܝܩ̈ܶܐ ܘܒ݂ܳܣܶܝܢ ܥܰܠ ܟ݁ܽܠܢܳܫ}}
\item{\foreignlanguage{german}{Schwärmgeister}}
\item{ \texttt{ in principio erat verbum}  }
\end{itemize}














\end{document}  


I don't have all your fonts, so can't try your code, but maybe \babelfont[hebrew]{rm}[Scale=2]{SBL Hebrew}

Welcome to TeX.SE!

Adding the [scale] option worked great. Maybe it's just my middle aged eyes. But that hebrew was so very small to read.  Thanks!
